# vb.net event handlers automatically removed when editing form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

When I edit a windows form in vb.net, "Handles" directives are automatically removed.

Why?

[image]

Handles directives are automatically trimmed away from my form which in my case happens in 124 places rendering the application unresponsive to events.

I am not sure if this happens every time I edit the form, but it seems to almost always happen.

## edit

Tried to work around by turning off "pretty listing" but the problem is still there.

[image]

## edit 2

Updating to visual studio 17.5.1 did not fix the problem.

## edit 3

Trying to uncheck "Auto list members" had no effect

[image]

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: The screenshot is a diff view so I cannot represent it textually @jmcilhinney

Comment: Why is this so hard? Write down the steps that we can follow to see the same issue you're seeing. We have no idea what you've actually done because you haven't told us, so tell us. If we follow the steps and don't see the same result then it's obviously an issue with your system. If we do see the same result then we can tell you what to do differently to avoid it.

Comment: I have not done any steps beside opened the file for editing. If there is an error in my system, then the error is not reproducible. So it is not hard but impossible to do what you ask for.

Comment: Did you create [this thread](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?899303-Strange-behavior-VS2022(ver-17-5-0-)-Designer-!!!!)? If not then maybe it's a bug introduced in VS 17.5. If you can't provide us steps to reproduce and we haven't seen it ourselves, what can we do? I've opened a form in VS 1``7.5 and not seen this issue, so it's obviously not universal. Maybe you could spend some time trying to work out the specific circumstances in which it occurs. I guess, in the meantime, all you can do is refresh the code form source control.

Comment: I did not create the thread. I would be helped by others confirming the behavior and by workaround suggestions. A comment on the page suggests that source control would be possible to use to remedy the problem. Yes, diff views are great and I need to use it on 124 places every time I edit the code (and I do not remove components).

Comment: VS 17.5.1 has been released. Hopefully that was an issue introduced in 17.5.0 that has now been addressed. it may be worthwhile checking the release notes.

Comment: Others with this problem: [one](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Handles-keep-missing-in-VBNet/10289798), [two](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VSnet-1750-Designer---Handles-for-man/10292652).  Might take a while when nobody provides repro steps.  Only sensible advice is to stay away from any VS version >= 17.4.0, they are far too buggy.

Answer (score 3):

It is a known issue:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Event-handlers-disconnect-from-the-objec/10291096

It will be fixed in VS 17.6.0 Preview 2.0.

Comment: It was never fixed!

Comment: It is fixed now in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.5.3. Please update your Visual Studio.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Form-Events-lost-on-compile-and-run-afte/10283572

Answer (score 1):

I was suffering exactly the same problem, seemingly random removal of all handles clauses. I did a repair of Visual Studio installation and so far it seems to haves cured the problem

Comment: I tried to repair vs 2022 but still, please tell me if it reappears for you.

Comment: Which version do you use?